# Need to redirect from one URL to another using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect one URL to another URL using my .htaccess file.

I have this link: http://example.org/download/p/fileId_1050/productId_354, which currently gives me a 404 error I want this to redirect it to this link: http://example.org/publication/9-steps-to-procuring-accessible-icts-for-inclusive-education.

I have tried this so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org\download\p\fileId_1050\productId_354$ RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.org/publication/9-steps-to-procuring-accessible-icts-for-inclusive-education/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rewriterule looked like it was rewriting every request to that URL and your syntax was incorrect.

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^download/p/fileId_1050/productId_354$  http://example.org/publication/9-steps-to-procuring-accessible-icts-for-inclusive-education [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Burm its still gives me a 404 error, is it because i am using some other commands in my htaccess file

Comment: What if you place this rule at the very top?